# SQL Access: Multiple Inner Join between Two Tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, inner-join

I'm working in Microsoft Access.

I have two tables, Production and Reagents.

```
Reagents
- Reagent Reference ID (text)
- Supplier (text)

Production
- Production Reference ID (text)
- C Reference ID (text) (matches Reagents.Reagent Reference ID)
- P Reference ID (text) (matches Reagents.Reagent Reference ID)
```

I'm trying to build a query to link the Supplier of C and P (from Reagents) to the Production Reference ID (from Production), as below.

```
Query Output
- Production Reference ID
- C Supplier
- P Supplier
```

Below is what I've got so far, but it tells me I'm missing an operator.

```
SELECT C.Supplier as 'C Supplier', P.Supplier as 'P Supplier'
FROM Production
INNER JOIN Reagents AS C ON C.Reagent Reference ID=Production.C Reference ID
INNER JOIN Reagents AS P ON P.Reagent Reagent Reference ID=Production.P Reference ID
WHERE Production.Production Reference ID=?
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So C reference ID and P reference ID are identical?

Comment: C Reference ID would be along the lines of C00001, while P Reference ID would be along the lines of P00001, and P and C will never match. Both P Reference ID and C Reference Reference IDs are included under the Reagent Reference ID.

Comment: Not sure if you strictly need a join, but I gave a solution using subqueries below. I tested it with a similar table on my own access database, and it worked. Beware of slowness if you exceed a couple thousand records and have no where conditional though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this method (this is using subqueries, beware it may be somewhat slow if the table is big):

```
SELECT Production.[Production Reference ID],
(SELECT Reagents.Supplier FROM Reagents WHERE Reagents.[Reagent Reference ID] = Production.[C Reference ID] ) as CSupplier, 
(SELECT Reagents.Supplier FROM Reagents WHERE Reagents.[Reagent Reference ID] = Production.[P Reference ID] ) as PSupplier
FROM Production;
```

Edit: With some Testing, I found out how it works in JOIN too, and it's a lot faster then method 1:

```
SELECT C.Supplier as 'C Supplier', P.Supplier as 'P Supplier'
FROM ( Production
INNER JOIN Reagents AS C ON C.[Reagent Reference Number]=Production.[C Reference Number] )
INNER JOIN Reagents AS P ON P.[Reagent Reagent Reference Number]=Production.[P Reference Number]
WHERE Production.[Production Reference Number]=?
```

MS Access requires parentheses when using more then one JOIN in a query.

Comment: This works perfectly for me - the tables are never going to get too big, so this should work well for it for the foreseeable future. Many thanks!

Comment: @JamesBoxall Keep in mind you can accept one of the answers to indicate that it worked for you by clicking the green checkmark next to the votes. Also I think Stefan's answer will work if you put proper parentheses (access is finnicky with these).

Comment: @JamesBoxall I figured out a JOIN version too, was lacking parentheses. This one is faster, too.

Comment: Thanks for your help! First time asking questions on SO, but I have now accepted the answers! :)

Comment: @JamesBoxall You can only accept one answer, not multiple "answers".

Answer (score 0):

Try encapsulating your fieldnames on brackets[], like below.

```
SELECT C.Supplier as 'C Supplier', P.Supplier as 'P Supplier'
FROM Production
INNER JOIN Reagents AS C ON C.[Reagent Reference Number]=Production.[C Reference Number]
INNER JOIN Reagents AS P ON P.[Reagent Reagent Reference Number]=Production.[P Reference Number]
WHERE Production.[Production Reference Number]=?
```

Comment: This looks to me like it should work, but it gives me the error:
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'C.[Reagent Reference Number]=Production.[C Reference Number]
INNER JOIN Reagents AS P ON P.[Reagent Reagent Reference Number]=Production.[P Reference Number'.

Comment: You have a common mistake in there. MS Access requires parentheses when using more then one JOIN.

Comment: I needed brackets around my first inner join, as below:
FROM (Production
INNER JOIN Reagents AS C ON C.[Reagent Reference Number]=Production.[C Reference Number]) INNER JOIN ...
With the brackets in place, this works great!

- Apologies Magisch, only just noticed your comment!